# ActionController::UnknownFormat: with rspec and get request (Rails5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to do controller test with rspec on rails 5 but I alway get a "ActionController::UnknownFormat" exception when running the tests.

Here is the error message:

```
 Failure/Error: get :index

 ActionController::UnknownFormat:
   MessagesController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant.

   request.formats: ["text/html"]
   request.variant: []

 NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, not nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot.
```

Here is the rspec code:

```
require 'rails_helper'
describe MessagesController do
  describe 'GET #index' do
    it "renders the :index template" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to render_template :index
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the controller code:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
```

Here is the route code:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :messages, only: [:index]
end
```

I made view file in views/messages/index.html.haml.
Usually, I can see the view file on web browser, using local environment.
However, on rspec, it cannot find the view file. I cannot understand.

Any idea what went wrong?
I'm in trouble. Please help me

Comment: Have a look at the response object, it will probably explain whats going on.
Please add a print of that to the question

Comment: have you added `gem 'rails-controller-testing'` to your gemfile?